# Can't set text label in table view in Xcode for the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have this code:

```
tableList  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First View",@"Second View",nil];
```

I have synthesized it and set the property, the problem is when I add this line under the configure the cell comment to set the text of each row, the app opens in the simulator but instantly closes:

```
// Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Any ideas on what is causing this ?

Comment: Is there an error message in the console?

Comment: If you're getting an index: beyondBounds: crash, then you need to make sure that your table has no more rows than the tableList array has elements.

Comment: Thanks very much cdespinosa , it worked straight away. I didnt realise that the problem was being caused by somthing so simple. If you make a post here I can vote you as the selected answer if you'd like?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting an index: beyondBounds: crash, then you need to make sure that your table has no more rows than the tableList array has elements.

Comment: Your time and efforts are really appreciated :)